# How do I stop my html/css/jquery menu text moving when the submenu us displayed?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I have seen many questions about making menus appear and disappear and I have found a solution to that problem which works on both desktop and tablet devices (well, those I have tried it on anyway), I did it using the jQuery .toggleClass function which works like a dream.

In this menu system I have a single "Menu" label which, when clicked, displays a drop down menu with some links in it. If you click the "Menu" label again then the drop down menu disappears. The problem I have is that when you click on the "Menu" text to display the submenu, the word "Menu" moves a bit to the right. When you click to hide the menu it moves back again, I want it to stay where I put it in the first place!

I believe that it is the CSS part that needs tweaking and have tried using the "left" property in pretty much every place I thought it would work, but to no avail.

I created this is jfiddle but in there the word "menu" doesn't even appear. If you want to look at the code there the the link is http://jsfiddle.net/wardmw/JpgRP/

The web page itself is viewable and has the menu button visible here: http://www.widowssons-southeast.org.uk/National/main.html

The CSS is as follows:

```
#nav {
    padding:0;
    margin:60px 0 0 0;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode';
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
    left: -80px;
    z-index:30;
}
/* #nav>li is the "Menu" option itself. There is only one li */
#nav li {
    position:relative;
    font-weight: semibold;
    align: right;
    width:192px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 10px;
    float:right;
    display: inline-table;
    border-right: 0px solid #d8d8d8;
}
#nav ul.sub-nav {
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #efefef;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
#nav ul.visible {
    display: inline-table;
}
#nav ul li {
    border-right: 0px solid #d8d8d8;
    line-height:20px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
}
#nav ul li a {
color:#132d3c;
font-size:15px;
font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode';
text-decoration: none;
}
```

The HTML script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function() {
        $('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});

</script>
```

The HTML menu itself:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="menudiv">
        <!-- This is the right-hand of the three columns in the header -->
        <ul id="nav">
            <li class="parent">Menu</li>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li><a href="who.html">Who we are</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="what.html">What we do</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="where.html">Where we are</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="links.html">Who we like</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- menudiv -->
    <div id="left">
        <!-- This is the left hand of the three columns -->
        <img border="0" src="images/ws-logo.png" width="1" height="1" alt="WSMBA" />
    </div>
    <!-- left -->
    <div id="middle">
        <!-- This is the middle of the three columns -->
    </div>
    <!-- middle -->
</div>
<!-- header -->
<p />Main page text.
```

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

|/|artin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an update to your jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JpgRP/1/

Working fine.

modified:

```
#nav ul.visible {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and mainly  removed float:right, align:right from nav li.

Comment: Sadly that has made no difference, the word "Menu" still moves to the right when the menu itself is displayed, and back again when the menu is hidden.

Comment: No it doesn't, have you seen the fiddle link mentioned in the answer. It's working as it should be.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong jsFiddle. The change you provided works great, thaanks very much for the assistance!

Comment: It's fine, atleast upvote the post, it may help others having the same problem..:)

Comment: I have marked it as accepted, I think, at least I ticked the green ticket anyway. Sadly I don't have enough reputation to upvote it (only 12). I will work on that and upvote this as soon as I am allowed to.